# What is the difference between 'String' and 'Text' in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I have following code which takes both string and text as datatype; but I am confused as to what exactly differs them?

```
 export class Owner {
    CompanyName: string;
    Description: Text;
}
```

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition Update 3 and Typescript 1.8+.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The types are not something specific to Angular 2 - it's TypeScript. That code would compile without the Angular 2 dependency.

To answer your question, there is no `Text` basic type in TypeScript. You can see them [all here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html). `Text` would then likely be an [interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) or [class](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html), which can be used as types.

`string` on the other hand, refers to the string primitive type in JavaScript (and TypeScript).

---

To further elaborate, [`Text`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) is an interface describing the capabilities of an HTMLElement (or TextNode) without markup content. Like you mention in your comment, it is include in `lib.d.ts`, which is described [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/lib.d.ts.html) as

> A special declaration file (that) ships with every installation of TypeScript. This file contains the ambient declarations for various common JavaScript constructs present in JavaScript runtimes and the DOM.

Comment: Yes, you are right,Thanks. it is an interface; By peeking its definition in visual studio-I figured that It is located in node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.d.ts.I could declare a variable using it without any warning or error but I am not sure whether any values can be attached to it or not.

Comment: @KaranDesai see my update above for further clarification